# Dropbox and LibreOffice don't like my Icelandic file names (Elementary OS, Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: files, libreoffice, dropbox, special-characters

I have some strange bugs possibly related to character encoding or problems with filenames, here are some clues:

Clue #1: LibreOffice Writer 4.1 won't open files with Icelandic characters in the file name (f.ex. Ritgerð.doc and Skýrsla.docx) but when I change the name to Ritgerd.doc or Skyrsla.docx can open the files and save without any problems.

Clue #2: Dropbox won't sync files with Icelandic characters in the file name. And as with LibreOffice, if I rename the files they will be synced.

Clue #3: Shortly after I got the other bugs (but only like one day later), the Icelandic keys on my keyboard stopped being Icelandic in Google Chrome Beta ("æ" became ";"), event though I had the right keyboard layout installed. I switched to Google Chrome Stable and din't encounter this after that.

Clue #4: This seems to have happened after I used the apt-get autoremove command.

Does anyone have an idea about what is going on?

[UPDATE]

I am using ext2 filesystem and when I try to open files with Icelandic characters in their file names I get an error from LibreOffice saying that "/home/traustid/Dropbox/Sagnagrunnur/Skￃﾽrsla og ritgerￃﾰ - Heimildaskrￃﾡ.doc does not exist." (with Icelandic characters really messed up).

Comment: On which filesystem type are the files stored? (ext4, ntfs...) And, what kind of error do you have when you say "It won't open"? From where/to where is syncing dropbox (remember that NTFS and Windows are much more restrictive on file names than Linux-native filesystems, and that the set of forbidden chars is different between the two).

Comment: I am using ext2 filesystem and when I try to open files with Icelandic characters in their file names I get an error from LibreOffice saying that "/home/traustid/Dropbox/Sagnagrunnur/Skￃﾽrsla og ritgerￃﾰ - Heimildaskrￃﾡ.doc does not exist." (with Icelandic characters really messed up). I am not using Dropbox to sync between computers since I only have one now, I'm basically using it for backup.

Comment: Seems that you have the filenames coded in UTF-8 but then LO is trying to read them in another coding (probably Latin-something). What does `env | grep LANG`  say? Mine says `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` confirming the use of UTF=8...

Comment: It says the same, LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, I solved this problem by installing Icelandic (Language for menus and windows) in the Language Support dialog in System Settings.